# a request-method in java that implements long-polling

Tags: multithreading, sockets

I have already written a request-method  in java that sends a request to a simple Server. I have written this simple server and the Connection is based on sockets. When the server has the answer for the request, it will send it automatically to client. Now I want to write a new method that can behave as following:

**if the server does not answer after a fixed period of time, then I send a new Request to the server using my request-method**

My problem is to implement this idea. I am thinking in launching a thread, whenever the request-method is executed. If this thread does not hear something for fixed period of time, then the request method should be executed again. But how can I hear from the same socket used between that client and server?

I am also asking,if there is a simpler method that does not use threads

curently I am working on this idea
    I am working on this idea:

```
1)send a request using my request-method
2)launch a thread for hearing from socket
3)If(no answer){   go to (1)}
  else{
      exit
  }
```

I have some difficulties in step 3. How I can go to (1)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish this with a single thread using a [SocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) and a [Selector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html), see also these tutorials on [SocketChannel](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/socketchannel.html) and [Selector](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html).  The gist of it is that you'll use long-polling on the `Selector` to let you know when your `SocketChannel(s)` are ready to read/write/etc using `Selector#select(long timeout)`.  (`SocketChannel` supports non-blocking, but from your problem description it sounds like things would be simpler using blocking)

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("http://jenkov.com", 80));
Selector selector = Selector.open();
SelectionKey key = socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
// returns the number of channels ready after 5000ms; if you have
// multiple channels attached to the selector then you may prefer
// to iterate through the SelectionKeys
if(selector.select(5000) > 0) {
    SocketChannel keyedChannel = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
    // read/write the SocketChannel
} else {
    // I think your best bet here is to close and reopen the Socket
    // or to reinstantiate a new socket - depends on your Request method
}
```

Comment: I will try your Idea/Implementation

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this idea:
1)send a request using my request-method
2)launch a thread for hearing from socket
3)If(no answer) then go to (1)